# printing a 2d array read from a txt file displays wrong in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, loops, printing

i am new to c++ and i would really appreciate some help with my following problem:

i have dynamically allocated space for a 2d int array of N rows and two columns the following way :

```
int **input;   
input = new int *[N];     
for (int count = 0; count < N; count++)   
      input[count] = new int[2];
```

when i print its contents in the while-loop in which i "fill" the array the actual contents are printed :

```
while (!myfileafter.eof())
{
     int temp1,temp2;    
     int i=0; 
     int j=0;

     myfileafter >> temp1>>temp2;  

     input[i][j]=temp1;      
     input [i][j+1] = temp2;

     i++;
     j=0;

     cout<<input[i-1][j]<<" "<<input[i-1][j+1]<<endl;
}
     // for (int p=0;p<N;p++)
     // cout<<input[p][0]<<" "<<input[p][1]<<endl;
```

however , if i use the two commented-out lines just after the while loop the array seems to contain totally different contents than the right ones printed before and this is the cause of many problems in the rest of the programm . any idea how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the contents of the file do not match with the length of your array.

Try this:

```
int temp1,temp2;
int i=0; 
int j=0;
while ( i < N && myfileafter >> temp1>> temp2 )
{    

  input[i][j]=temp1;      
  input[i][j+1] = temp2;
  i++;
  j=0;
  cout<<input[i-1][j]<<" "<<input[i-1][j+1]<<endl;
}
// Note the termination condition. It is uncertain whether all N locations have been filled.
for (int p=0;p<i;p++) 
  cout<<input[p][0]<<" "<<input[p][1]<<endl;
```

**EDIT: Instead of using a 2D Nx2 array, I would suggest you to use 2 1D arrays to avoid possible errors and for code clarity.** Or better still, use two 1D vectors.

With pointers you will have to take care of deleting the allocating memory.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the loop you set i to zero, so you're always reading into input[0].

It's better to use the actual reading as the condition:

```
int i = 0;
while ( my_file_after >> input[i][0] >> input[i][1] ) ++i;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd recommend is to practice formatting your code more consistently. There are some accepted conventions that can make your code a lot more readable. Only changing formatting, I'd recommend something like this:

```
while (!myfileafter.eof())
{
    int temp1,temp2;    
    int i=0; 
    int j=0;

    myfileafter >> temp1 >> temp2;      
    input[i][j] = temp1;      
    input [i][j+1] = temp2;
    i++;
    j=0;

    cout << input[i-1][j] << " " << input[i-1][j+1] << endl;
}
//for (int p=0; p < N; p++)
//{
//    cout << input[p][0] << " " << input[p][1] << endl;
//}
```

I'm sure it's also possible that you formatted it correctly and it just got messed up when you entered it here, but proper formatting can make a world of difference.

Moving on... gahh! Carl beat me to it: you're overwriting input[0] every time.

The only thing I'll add is that the cout inside your loop is a bit deceptive because it will print out what you expect it to, but it's printing it from input[0][0] and input[0][1] every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are other answers here that explain what is wrong with your code specifically, but I'll also add some other information about how you're approaching the array allocation itself.

Typically speaking, an array (unless it's some STL or other intelligent/class array) is a contiguous piece of memory.  Then an additional array points to that. In other words, for foo[X][Y] you're creating foo[X] first then adding the [Y] component after the fact, individually, instead of creating a contiguous [X*Y] piece of memory then having each foo[X] element point to the first element of each [Y]. Visually, you're doing this:

```
foo -|
     |
     |
     | [...]
```

then each int individually like

```
foo -| -- _
         |_
     | -- _
         |_
     | -- _
         |_
     | [...]
```

when you should be allocating the entire int chunk as one piece because 1) if you do a lot of small allocations like this it tends to kill performance (not that important for you here I don't think) and b) pointer arithmetic will actually work if the array is properly created.

Let's say you have the following chunks:
`foo` is an array of `int*` that starts at ADDRESS_X and is 4 elements long. For your example you need 4 elements * 2 columns = 8 `int`s total.  So you create a contiguous 8 `int` long array that starts at `ADDRESS_Y`.  You'd then want to do this (pseudocode-ish here):

```
int **foo = new int *[SIZE_OF_X]; // an array of 4 pointers
int *bar = new int[SIZE_OF_X * NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]; // in other words, 8 ints

for (i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_X; i++) {
    foo[i] = &bar + (i * SIZE_OF_X);
}
```

Where bar is:

```
    ADDRESS_Y + 0: 10
    ADDRESS_Y + 1: 20
    ADDRESS_Y + 2: 30
    ...
```

And foo is:

```
    ADDRESS_X + 0: ADDRESS_Y
    ADDRESS_X + 1: ADDRESS_Y + 2
    ...
```

so foo[1][0] == 30.